# how to change HTML page title within a site wide template for catalogs?

Tags: business-catalyst

Within a site wide template I have edited the "title" tag, but when going to a catalog and viewing the source it holds a different title and I'm unable where to find it to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Admin Console, go to the catalog and specify the title in the catalog title text box.

Comment: answering your own questions  is always a nice way of doing it